# Paste using SendKeys not going to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to simply paste into a cell in Excel. But instead it pastes into my VBA code editor.

```
Application.Worksheets("ABC").Cells(6, 86).Select
Application.SendKeys "^(v)", True
```

Appreciate help!

Comment: Why are you trying to sendkeys a paste command to an excel cell? Why not just store what you want in a variable and set the cell to that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `Sendkeys`?

`Sendkeys` is highly unreliable. Why not this?

```
 Worksheets("ABC").Cells(6, 86).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a DoEvents:

```
Sub demo()
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.SendKeys ("^c")
    DoEvents
    Range("B9").Select
    Application.SendKeys ("^v")
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason using DoEvents causes it to now not paste anything at all. I got it to work by using the Paste function instead of SendKeys, not sure what is wrong

Comment: @Jaqx  You posted only part of you code..........try my code on a new worksheet with something in cell **A1**